# JSF navigation using h:commandButton and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe into my JSF application and am having difficulty navigating away from the "add credit card" page.  Everything works, except after the user hits submit, the page does not navigate away.

Below is the addCreditCard.xhtml facelet.  Adding the javascript logic as a submit eventListener and triggering the bean update method() using `onclick="#{stripeCCBean.update()}"` was the only way I could get the javascript to successfully create the token (the createToken method would fail if the javascript was triggered by onclick for some unknown reason) AND get the bean to recognize the hidden fields.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml"
      xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
    <head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/StripeCCTokenize.css"/>
        <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/js/StripeCCTokenize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="addCC" pt:action="/secure/addCreditCard.xhtml" pt:method="POST">

        <h:inputHidden id="cardholder-name" value="#{userManagerBean.user.fullName}"/>

        We loaded your customer details (name, email and customer ID) from the backend database:

        <label>
            Hello #{userManagerBean.user.firstName} #{userManagerBean.user.lastName}
        </label>
        <label>
            E-Mail - #{userManagerBean.user.email}
        </label>
        <label>
            Stripe Customer ID - #{userManagerBean.stripeUser.id}
        </label>
        <h:outputText value="Please enter the requested credit card and billing information below"/>
        <span>Address</span>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Address" />
            <h:inputText class="field" id="address1" value="#{stripeCCBean.card.address1}" pt:placeholder="Street address"/>
            <h:outputText value="Address"/>
            <h:inputText class="field" id="address2" value="#{stripeCCBean.card.address2}" pt:placeholder="Street address"/>
            <h:outputText value="City" />
            <h:inputText class="field" id="city" value="#{stripeCCBean.card.city}" pt:placeholder="city"/> 
            <h:outputText value="State" />
            <h:inputText class="field" id="state" value="#{stripeCCBean.card.state}" pt:placeholder="state"/>
            <h:outputText value="zip" /> 
            <h:inputText class="field" id="address-zip" value="#{stripeCCBean.card.zipcode}" pt:placeholder="zipcode"/>
            <h:outputText value="cc"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <div id="card-element" class="field"></div>

        <h:commandButton value="Add Credit Card" onclick="#{stripeCCBean.update()}" type="submit" id="addButton"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Here is the StripeCCTokenize.js:

```
var stripe; var card;

$(document).ready(function () {
    stripe = Stripe('pk_test_key');
    var elements = stripe.elements();

card = elements.create('card', {
    hidePostalCode: true,
    style: {
        base: {
            iconColor: '#F99A52',
            color: '#32315E',
            lineHeight: '48px',
            fontWeight: 400,
            fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", sans-serif',
            fontSize: '15px',
            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#CFD7DF'
            }
        }
    }
});
card.mount('#card-element');

function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('addCC');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);

    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
}

function setOutcome(result) {
    if (result.token) {
        // Use the token to create a charge or a customer
        // https://stripe.com/docs/charges

        console.log("Token: " + result.token.id);
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);

    } 
}

card.on('change', function (event) {
    setOutcome(event);
});

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var extraDetails = {
        address_line1: document.getElementById('addCC:address1').value,
        address_line2: document.getElementById('addCC:address2').value,
        address_city: document.getElementById('addCC:city').value,
        address_state: document.getElementById('addCC:state').value,
        address_zip: document.getElementById('addCC:address-zip').value,
        name: document.getElementById('addCC:cardholder-name').value
    };
    console.log(extraDetails);
    stripe.createToken(card, extraDetails).then(setOutcome);
    });
});
```

Here is the stripeCCBean class:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@ToString
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "stripeCCBean")
public class StripeCCBean implements Serializable {

    StripeCard card;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{stripeServiceBean}")
    private StripeServiceBean stripeServiceBean;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{userManagerBean}")
    private UserManagerBean userManagerBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("StripeCCBean.init()");
        card = new StripeCard();
        card.setName(userManagerBean.getUser().getFullName());
    }

    public void update() throws IOException {
        String token = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("stripeToken");

        if (token == null) {
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("StripeCCBean.update()");

        System.out.println("Token: " + token);
        System.out.println("Card: " + card);

        try {
            StripeService.addCard(userManagerBean.getStripeUser().getId(), token);
        } catch (AuthenticationException | APIConnectionException | CardException | APIException | InvalidRequestException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I tried adding `action="#{stripeCCBean.viewAccount()}"` to the `<h:commandButton .../>` and the corresponding method to the StripeCCBean:

```
public String viewAccount() {
    return "AccountView";
}
```

However the form simply runs the Javascript, calls the stripeCCBean.update() (everything works) and then stays on that page.  The customer information fields do not get cleared, however the credit card element does.

I tried adding `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/secure/AccountView.xhtml");` 
as well as 
`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("/secure/AccountView.xhtml");` to the stripeCCBean.update() method and neither works.  In fact, they throw an exception.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  If I'm triggering the JS incorrectly or inefficiently, I'm happy to change that as well.

Comment: Things I see strange in this question: 1. Can't see where do you call javascript from your xhtml file. 2. If the bean is meant to manage a view, use `@ViewScoped` instead of `@RequestScoped` (you will lose the state from request to request otherwise). 3. I would rather call the `init` method using `f:viewAction` instead of a `@PostConstruct` annotation. 4. Do not use `action` and `method` attributes in JSF forms. JSF takes care of calculating them for yourself. 5. The `h:commandButton`'s `onclick` attribute should execute a javascript listener instead of a server side method..

Comment: @XtremeBiker, 1) The JS is fired via event handler (`document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', ... `)   2) The bean just performs some business logic.  It's not completed, and so will eventually persist the results of the addCard(...) method to a @SessionScoped bean.  3) Answered by #2?  4) I could not get the JSF form to trigger the javascript, persist the hidden fields to the form AND call the bean method without the passthrough form attributes.  I don't know why, it just wouldn't work.  5) When the JS was triggered by onclick, the createToken() method failed, no idea why.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I realize the code is a bit all over the place, but only because I couldn't get things to work when doing it the 'right way'.  Looks like there are some suggestions below I will try.

Comment: Mmh, yes, I see.. Have you tried rushing some simililar example and seeing what's going on? I mean, set up a view (doesn't need to be a whole project) and do what you want to do but with a minimal JS code and minimal managed bean functionality, instead of getting stripe-payment utilities involved.

Answer (score 0):

Another one of those "I have no idea why this worked", but I tried adding `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/secure/AccountView.xhtml");` to the end of the stripeCCBean.update() method and now it works.

Still no idea why I have to have the update() method called via the commandButton's onclick though...

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the preventDefault function which prevents the browse default behaviour and you need not use the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate by a f:commandButton / f:commandLink, use the action attribute instead of onclick.

```
<f:commandButton ... action="#{myBean.actionHandler}".../>
```

If you don't use any ajax mechanism, the bean can be `@RequestScoped`, other case `@ViewScoped`

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean
{
  public String actionHandler()
  {
    ...
    return "navigationRuleName";
  }

  ...
}
```

Where `navigationRuleName` is registered in the `faces-config.xml`:

```
<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/path/source.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>navigationRuleName</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/path/targetPageName.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect/>
  </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Or it can be a page name:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean
{
  public String actionHandler()
  {
    ...
    return "/path/targetPageName.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
  }

  ...
}
```

Or the xhtml extension can be omitted.

The '' entity or the `faces-redirect=true` parameter necessary if you want the location URL of the browser changing to targetPageName.xhtml after the HTTP POST request-response navigation. Redirection do it by another HTTP GET call after the HTTP POST one.